# Eleven community wiki answers to a question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, community-wiki

The "oldie but goodie" question [What are the choices today for orbital mechanics simulation software?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/646/12102) has eleven separate community wiki answers (more if you count the deleted ones).

**Questions:**

1. Would the ideal situation *in this particular case* be a consolidation of at least all of the *short answers* into one CW but perhaps leaving the really long answers as separate?
2. If "yes", is it too late now to go back and implement that?

Comment: Who was the mysterious User29

Comment: @JCRM That was Chris. He was one of the original pro tem mods--the one I replaced when he stepped down.

Comment: @uhoh That question was intended to be a broad repository that everyone can contribute to. A practice that we use very sparingly (see the note on the original question). I do think if we made it today we would be more inclined to include most answers in a single answer post, but we have never enforced that and even on the more recent CW questions we have not enforced that and sometimes have gotten some additional answer posts. As far as how to handle cleaning up old questions--I don't think we should remove a bunch of answers, but I think there is room for an answer that consolidates info...

Comment: ...from the other answers.

Comment: @called2voyage I'm not sure what you mean by "there is room for" in terms of actions and results. Do you mean a new wiki with stuff from each of the small wikis then those small ones are deleted? Do you mean something a mod would do? Or do you mean yet another answer in addition to the existing ones with duplication of information from them?

Comment: @uhoh I mean any user can come along and make a summary answer if they would like to help consolidate things.

Comment: @uhoh And yes, it would be more duplication and yet another answer, but it may be a worthwhile tradeoff if it gets voted up where it has the greatest visibility.